# XFX RX580 8gb screen goes black HDMI sound pops then silent for a few seconds then working again

Tags: hdmi, vga

XFX RX580 8gb screen goes black HDMI sound pops then silent for a few seconds then working again

I have a workstation HP Z210 with upgraded psu 700w and an XFX rx580 8gb. cpu: i7 2600 with 8gb elpida ram + ssd + hdd +WIN10
My better half has an PC with 650w psu, XFX rx580 8g, Asrock mobo, i5 4590, 8gb ram, ssd + hdd + WIN10

We both use  the same Aopen FHD 144Hz Freesync monitor with hdmi cable. All AMD drivers are up to date.

When we play games, especialy Dying Light in some cases the screen turn blask for a few seconds on my pc. When it happens also HDMI sound pops and goes silent then returns. I cant find a pattern.

For my wife, the same happens in windows no games running.

What do you think could be causing this?
Where should I start the debug?

Comment: Sounds like the common factor is the monitor. I would eliminate that as a factor

Comment: Could it happen that both monitor has problem? Previously there was an old EVGA GTX 560TI in my wife's PC and there was no problem at all.